# How get around solr's spellcheck maxEdit limit of 2?

Tags: solr

I would like to provide results for words that are severly misspelled.  Do you have any suggestions on how I can that in solr 5.  The built in solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker doesn't seem to be very flexible.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider instead an analyzer stack that creates phonetic mapping or other transformations that reduce spelling to more-general representation. An example shows one of them ([DoubleMetaphone](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_5_3_1/solr/server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs/conf/schema.xml#L634)). But there are [many different ones](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/) depending on the possible reasons the words are being misspelt.

Comment: So I copied that example to get me started.  Unfortunately I seems like that using it prevents me from doing spellcheck at all.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Oh, I meant that instead of spell checker. As a thing to consider. I don't think it just plugs in instead. Can you provide more information on what kind of misspelling you get.

Comment: I'm working with a list of grapes.  Examples would be Abbuoto or Sárfehér or Tamâioasa Româneasca.  Thank you so much for your help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: You definitely need a spellchecker or would a suggester do? It has a lot more flexibility and you should be able to use phonetic mapping with some of them.

Comment: I setup the suggest example here [ https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester ] and it seems to be a lot better.  Do you have any suggestions on how to tweak it to handle accent characters?  You mentioned phonetic mapping, do you have an encoding you recommend.  Lastly, is there any way to combine spell check + suggestions into a single query (ie. first do a spellcheck, if that doesn't provide an answer then offer suggests).  Thanks for all your help.  I can't tell you how much I appreciate it.

Comment: You can combine spell check and suggester I believe by just adding both search components. But not conditionally. So, they will both run. As to accent and best phonetic mapping, you have a couple of filters - you just have to see what works best. Specifically for accents, there is general ASCII one or there is an ICU one that is more robust but requires extra library. Just look through the link provided in the answer for the full list. It is a good read.